# Best solution for execution sql file by golang gorm lib

Tags: go, go-gorm

Mabye someone have more simple code for execution sql file by gorm lib?

```
// CARRIERS IMPORT
err := DB.Session.Model(model.Carriers{}).Count(&carriers).Error
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
} else if carriers == 0 {
    path, err := filepath.Abs("./dumps/carriers.sql")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    file, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    DB.Session.Model(model.Carriers{}).Exec(string(file))
}
```

Comment: If your question about code-refactoring http://codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for it, otherwise rephrase your question.

Answer (score -1):

When executing a SQL file full of statements, the existing sql command-line clients do not just send the file contents over to the server. Instead, they parse the file and issue individual statements.

If you want to replicate this functionality, you will need to parse the file yourself into individual statements and execute them.

The easiest way is to invoke an external command-line client.
For example for postgresql you should [exec](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/) something like `psql [connection args] -f <sql file>`.